# Re-Ordering lists selectively, based on two elements LINQ

Tags: c#, json, linq, generics

I have a json object that I need to rearrange it by reordering child elements under the parents: (Current obj):

```
"groupFields": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Performance",
        "parentId": null,
        "parentName": null
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Engagement",
        "parentId": null,
        "parentName": null
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Websites",
        "parentId": 10,
        "parentName": "Conversions"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Apps",
        "parentId": 10,
        "parentName": "Conversions"
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Clicks",
        "parentId": 2,
        "parentName": "Engagement"
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Settings",
        "parentId": null,
        "parentName": null
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Conversions",
        "parentId": null,
        "parentName": null
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Page post",
        "parentId": 2,
        "parentName": "Engagement"
    },
    {
        "id": 13,
        "name": "Messaging",
        "parentId": 2,
        "parentName": "Engagement"
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "Media",
        "parentId": 2,
        "parentName": "Engagement"
    },
    {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "Awareness",
        "parentId": 2,
        "parentName": "Engagement"
    },
    {
        "id": 16,
        "name": "On Facebook",
        "parentId": 10,
        "parentName": "Conversions"
    },
    {
        "id": 17,
        "name": "Offline",
        "parentId": 10,
        "parentName": "Conversions"
    },
    {
        "id": 18,
        "name": "Store visits",
        "parentId": 10,
        "parentName": "Conversions"
    }
```

to be: (childs are coming after parents)

```
"groupFields": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Performance",
        "parentId": null,
        "parentName": null
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Engagement",
        "parentId": null,
        "parentName": null
    },
            {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Clicks",
        "parentId": 2,
        "parentName": "Engagement"
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Page post",
        "parentId": 2,
        "parentName": "Engagement"
    },
    {
        "id": 13,
        "name": "Messaging",
        "parentId": 2,
        "parentName": "Engagement"
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "Media",
        "parentId": 2,
        "parentName": "Engagement"
    },
    {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "Awareness",
        "parentId": 2,
        "parentName": "Engagement"
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Settings",
        "parentId": null,
        "parentName": null
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Conversions",
        "parentId": null,
        "parentName": null
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Websites",
        "parentId": 10,
        "parentName": "Conversions"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Apps",
        "parentId": 10,
        "parentName": "Conversions"
    },
    {
        "id": 16,
        "name": "On Facebook",
        "parentId": 10,
        "parentName": "Conversions"
    },
    {
        "id": 17,
        "name": "Offline",
        "parentId": 10,
        "parentName": "Conversions"
    },
    {
        "id": 18,
        "name": "Store visits",
        "parentId": 10,
        "parentName": "Conversions"
    }
```

I was thinking to get it sorted using LINQ (if it is the solution) but I can't manage to get the proper result, 
Initially, I tried to sort the collection using OrderBy(Id).ThenBy(ParentId), I didn't get what I wanted. Then I was thinking to separate them into two different lists:

```
var parentList = new Collection<GroupField>();
var childList = new Collection<GroupField>();

foreach (var source in sources)
{
    if (source.ParentGroupId == null) parentList.Add(source);
    if (source.ParentGroupId.HasValue) childList.Add(source);
}
var query = childList.Where(p => parentList.Any(c => c.ParentGroupId == p.Id)).ToList();
```

Neither of my solutions worked.

Comment: If there are only two generations (parent and child) you can use `.OrderBy( a => a.parentId == null ? 0 : 1 )`

Comment: You need to check if the item with same is not added to the parentList `if (source.ParentGroupId == null && parentList.All(d=>d.Id != source.id)) parentList.Add(source);`

Comment: Just to clarify you want to order entities #1 by being a parent or not #2 by id? So parents first by ID then childen first ordered by ID?

Comment: @KristófTóth Please refer to the (To Be) I posted above. parents come and children (if any) fill up after. => Parent,Children,NextParent,Children. Hope it clarifies the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code should do the trick.

```
var returnList = new List<GroupField>();
foreach (var source in sources.Where(s => s.ParentId == null).OrderBy(p => p.Id))
{
   returnList.Add(source);
   returnList.AddRange(sources.Where(s => s.ParentId != null && s.ParentId == source.Id).OrderBy(p => p.Id))
}

return returnList;
```

Comment: Bravo, clean and neat. Couldn't help, not to leave a comment to appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Time Complexity of the solution is O(n^2), may not work well for the collections with lots of data

Comment: Also Linq being lazy evaluation, it's not good to have statements within loops, it will keep evaluating every time and will impact performance, store the intermediary values in a structure like List

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the following version using `Grouping` and `Join`:

```
var allData = new List<GroupField>();

var parents = allData.Where(s => s.ParentId == null)
                 .OrderBy(p => p.Id);

var children = allData.Where(s => s.ParentId != null)
                  .GroupBy(p => p.ParentId);

var result = new List<GroupField>();

var finalResult =
parents.Join(children,
             p => p.Id, 
             c => c.Key,
(p,c) => 
{
    result.Add(p);
    result.AddRange(c.OrderBy(x => x.Id));
    return result;
});
```

> How it works

1. Fetch the Parent data from complete collection
2. Group the Child Data using `ParentId`
3. Join the two collections and final result will be in `finalResult`

Time Complexity - O(n)